# Ruby search in Array of Hashes with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I'm trying to query an array of hashes with 2 different conditions, but this is not working:

```
array_list = [
  {type: 'sale', currency: 'CAD', price: '123'},
  {type: 'purchase', currency: 'CAD', price: '321'}
]

if array_list.select { |pt|
  pt[:type] == 'sale', pt[:currency] == 'CAD'
}.present?

end
```

Any suggestions please?
Thanks

Comment: You wanted `pt[:type] == 'sale' && pt[:currency] == 'CAD'` instead.

Comment: Assignment in Ruby is a single `=`. There's an unexpected comma within the select block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `&&` also instead of using **[Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select)** and `present?` can use **[`Array#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-any-3F)**

```
array_list = [
  {type: 'sale', currency: 'CAD', price: '123'},
  {type: 'purchase', currency: 'CAD', price: '321'}
]

if array_list.any? { |pt| pt[:type] == 'sale' && pt[:currency] == 'CAD'}
  # your logic
end
```